# Built simple next.js app using API Routes for serverless calls. Simple API call is getting hung up and stuck pending?

Tags: node.js, next.js

**Submission page:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
// ... other imports

export default function ContestSubmission() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    file: null,
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value, type, files } = e.target;

    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: type === 'file' ? files[0] : value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Use formData to send the data
    const dataToSend = new FormData();
    dataToSend.append('firstName', formData.firstName);
    dataToSend.append('lastName', formData.lastName);
    dataToSend.append('email', formData.email);
    dataToSend.append('file', formData.file);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/contest-submission', dataToSend);

      if (response.data.success) {
        console.log('Submission successful');
      } else {
        console.error('Submission failed:', response.data.error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Request error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h2>Submit Your Entry</h2>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">

         // ... other form groups

          <Button className="enter-button" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**/api/contest-submission.js:**

```
const { config } = require('dotenv');
const formidable = require('formidable');
// ... other imports

config();

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const form = formidable({});
    form.uploadDir = './uploads';

    form.parse(req, (parseError, fields, files) => {
      if (parseError) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Error parsing form data.' });
        return;
      }

      const { firstName, lastName, email } = fields;
      const { file } = files;
      const ipAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress;
      const submissionTime = new Date(); // Get the current date and time

      const uniqueFileName = `${uuidv4()}.jpg`;
      const filePath = `${form.uploadDir}/${uniqueFileName}`;

      fs.rename(file.path, filePath, (renameError) => {
        if (renameError) {
          res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Error saving the file.' });
          return;
        }

        const connection = createDBConnection();

        connection.connect();

        const query =
          'INSERT INTO submissions (first_name, last_name, email, file_path, ip_address, submission_datetime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        connection.query(
          query,
          [firstName, lastName, email, uniqueFileName, ipAddress, submissionTime],
          (dbError) => {
            if (dbError) {
              res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Error inserting data into the database.' });
            } else {
              res.status(200).json({ success: true });
            }

            connection.end();
          }
        );
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ success: false, error: 'Method not allowed.' });
  }
}
```

It's fairly cut and try. Filling out the form and pressing submit, I see the payload is appropriately filled out. But, the request stays stuck on pending and never finishes. Further, I'm not seeing any of the console logs I've put out there.

I'm trying to avoid standing up an express server and just utilizing API Routes instead. To my knowledge, it was supposed to provide an built in way to avoid creating a separate server, and would handle all the api calls by default.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried to set `res.status(200)` when everything goes right as well?

Comment: Well, I know that it doesn't go right because nothing gets inserted into the database.

It seems I'm having some weird, specific issue with form.parse(). Once it reaches that line, it skips over everything in the code. It won't even enter it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the application is trying to connect to the database but the connection is unreachable.

That should be on line `const connection = createDBConnection();`

In order to verify this, you can add console.log statements before and after and check on the Lambda logs.

Make sure that the security group allows the database traffic from the service.